# Is HATEOAS in REST a CRUD-based model?

Tags: rest, crud, hateoas

I am curious whether HATEOAS is the skeleton of REST. If it is, is HATEOAS a CRUD-based model or not? If not, what is the difference?

I find applications that create CRUD applications from HATEOAS. Is that enough evidence to say HATEOAS is based on CRUD?

Answer (score 0):

> i am curious if hateoas is the skeleton of rest

Yes, see Fielding 2008: [REST APIs must be hypertext driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

> hateoas is a crud based model or not ?

Not necessarily, no.  In the case of the web, the primary hypermedia controls are links and forms.  Forms are used to send representations to the origin server, but the semantics of a form submission are not *necessarily* create/update/delete.